# Python Error during QField Packaging

Tags: qfield, qfieldsync

I am running QField in QGIS 3.22.3 and have successfully run it in the past.

Can someone help me to troubleshoot the issue with this Python error when I try to package my files in Qfield?

```
2022-02-05T22:31:07     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:\Users/grgsj/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\Greg/python/plugins\qfieldsync\gui\package_dialog.py", line 123, in package_project
              offline_convertor.convert()
              File "C:\Users/grgsj/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\Greg/python/plugins\qfieldsync\core\offline_converter.py", line 188, in convert
              copied_files = layer_source.copy(self.export_folder, copied_files)
              File "C:\Users/grgsj/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\Greg/python/plugins\qfieldsync\core\layer.py", line 234, in copy
              shutil.copy(os.path.join(source_path, basename + ext), dest_file)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 418, in copy
              copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 282, in copyfile
              _copyfileobj_readinto(fsrc, fdst, min(file_size, COPY_BUFSIZE))
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 195, in _copyfileobj_readinto
              fdst_write(mv)
             PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like you don't have write permission to the path where you try to package the files in. Can you try your Desktop or something similar that should definitely work?

Comment: The write permission may have to do with the file (or one with the same filepath) being opened by another program.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have created a greatly reduced workspace to try to troubleshoot this issue and am still getting the same error. I have confirmed that the referenced directories are not read only.  Also I am not accessing these files from any other program and am only running one QGIS application.  I am wondering if I should un-install QGIS and re-install it.  I was successfully using Qfield in version 3.16 and 3.18.